# Using CSP meta tag for script-src and style-src in normal html file

Tags: html, hashcode, content-security-policy, sha256, developer-tools

Here is my demo.html file where I am using CSP meta tag and external js and css files.

**demo.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' ; object-src 'none';
        style-src 'self';
        script-src 'sha256-Ql3n7tC/2D6wSTlQY8RcOKXhq02zfdaSDviOhpvbYWw=';
       " >
      <script src="scripts.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<p>Hello World</p>
<h2>JavaScript Alert</h2>

<button>Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my js file

```js
console.log("Hello");
```

Now I have used CSP meta tag and which accept sha256 hashcode to pass the js file i.e script-src and I have calculated the sha256 hashcode i.e **'sha256-Ql3n7tC/2D6wSTlQY8RcOKXhq02zfdaSDviOhpvbYWw='** which I have written in script-src. But still it is not accepted by the console. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is 3 issues:

1. The right hash for `console.log("Hello");` is ['sha256-efGKf8oWIWhXl5BsggWDZ+M7Bf5AirxrKOCBujdLAWg='](http://csplite.com/csp/sha/?pl=eJxLtDK0qi62MrFS8gjx9VGyLrYyMrRSSs7PK87PSdXLyU%2FXUPJIzcnJV9K0VrKuBQA8qg2%2B#result)
2. You need to add the `integrity=` attribute to allow external script via `'hash-value'`:
   `<script src="script.js" integrity='sha256-efGKf8oWIWhXl5BsggWDZ+M7Bf5AirxrKOCBujdLAWg='></script>`
3. Firefox browser still does [not support](http://csplite.com/csp/test161/#bug_Firefox_hash-source) `'hash-value'` to allow external scripts (Safari - too). Therefore use Chrome to observe result.

Answer (score 0):

SHA is a checksum computed for a specific script and should be loaded with it. Take a look at how it is used in well-known libraries. e.g. bootstrap

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

That what you try is nonce (128 bit) and can look like this:

```
// Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'dsd14e314df23e2d32r' 

<script nonce="dsd14e314df23e2d32r" src="https://app.domain.com/app.js"></script>
```